# Wireless stopped working after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, iwlwifi, 19.04

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 and soon Internet stopped working. Here is a portion of output for 'dmesg'

```
[ 8948.584615] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 8948.584616] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 8948.586419]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 8948.586499] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x8e
[ 8948.587886] microcode: updated to revision 0x9a, date = 2018-07-16
[ 8948.587972] CPU1 is up
[ 8948.587996] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[ 8948.588553]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 8948.588633] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x9a
[ 8948.588834] CPU2 is up
[ 8948.588858] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[ 8948.589357]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 8948.589537] CPU3 is up
[ 8948.593421] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 8948.618307] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[ 8948.660361] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[ 8948.661856] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 8948.670958] ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
[ 8948.911826] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 8948.974365] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 8949.043491] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[ 8949.043511] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 8949.043513] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 8949.043514] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[ 8949.043684] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[ 8949.048265] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 8949.048266] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 8949.048267] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[ 8949.048419] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[ 8949.048843] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 8949.195875] usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 8949.471880] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 8949.623771] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[ 8949.623907] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[ 8949.623982] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[ 8949.624140] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[ 8949.624279] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[ 8949.624403] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[ 8949.624470] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[ 8949.624621] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[ 8949.624758] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[ 8949.624894] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[ 8949.624962] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[ 8949.625115] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[ 8949.625175] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[ 8949.625243] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[ 8949.625377] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
[ 8949.625503] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[ 8949.625646] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
[ 8949.625713] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[ 8949.625849] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[ 8949.626004] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
[ 8949.626047] OOM killer enabled.
[ 8949.626048] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 8949.763526] PM: suspend exit
[ 8950.029770] ish-hid {33AECD58-B679-4E54-9BD9-A04D34F0C226}: [hid-ish]: enum_devices_done OK, num_hid_devices=4
[ 8950.054322] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[ 8950.055517] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[ 8950.340390] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[ 8953.532462] wlp1s0: authenticate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6
[ 8953.536675] wlp1s0: send auth to e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[ 8953.539869] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 8953.543728] wlp1s0: associate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[ 8953.547136] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[ 8953.571514] wlp1s0: associated
[ 8953.586810] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[ 8955.332607] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[ 8955.332733] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[ 8958.809493] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[ 8960.902403] ACPI Error: Thread 4073029632 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 3845185024 (20181213/exmutex-382)
[ 8960.902414] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q66]
[ 8960.902415] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q66]
[ 8960.902416] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_AML_NOT_OWNER (20181213/psparse-531)
[ 8965.366308] input: 88:C6:26:69:E2:07 as /devices/virtual/input/input29
[10406.192427] ACPI Error: Thread 4092386816 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 4083488640 (20181213/exmutex-382)
[10406.192434] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q66]
[10406.192435] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q66]
[10406.192436] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_AML_NOT_OWNER (20181213/psparse-531)
[11364.905029] perf: interrupt took too long (2501 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[15510.188071] input: 88:C6:26:69:E2:07 as /devices/virtual/input/input30
[16576.072095] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[16576.072102] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[16576.096530] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
[16576.101237] OOM killer disabled.
[16576.101239] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[16576.103070] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[16576.104635] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[16576.132078] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[16576.141733] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[16576.357325] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[16576.396567] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[16576.401512] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[16576.401513] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[16576.401514] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[16576.401600] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[16576.403036] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[16576.407373] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[16576.410871] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[16576.416041] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[16576.416128] ACPI: EC: EC started
[16576.416128] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[16576.418238] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[16576.418296] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[16576.418296] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[16576.418798]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[16576.418881] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x8e
[16576.420345] CPU1 is up
[16576.420407] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[16576.420972]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[16576.421053] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x9a
[16576.421256] CPU2 is up
[16576.421306] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[16576.421805]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[16576.421977] CPU3 is up
[16576.425864] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[16576.450935] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[16576.511128] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[16576.512460] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[16576.763721] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[16576.826896] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[16576.826918] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[16576.899347] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[16576.899378] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[16576.899381] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[16576.899418] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[16576.903375] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[16576.903379] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[16576.903382] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[16576.903493] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[16576.903934] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[16577.039715] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[16577.315726] usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[16577.864949] ish-hid {33AECD58-B679-4E54-9BD9-A04D34F0C226}: [hid-ish]: enum_devices_done OK, num_hid_devices=4
[16578.773299] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[16578.773529] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[16578.773752] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[16578.773974] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[16578.774195] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[16578.774414] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[16578.774633] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[16578.774855] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[16578.775075] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[16578.775294] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[16578.775623] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[16578.775845] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[16578.776062] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[16578.776282] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[16578.776499] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
[16578.776733] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[16578.776931] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
[16578.777128] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[16578.777325] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[16578.777520] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
[16578.777651] OOM killer enabled.
[16578.777652] Restarting tasks ... done.
[16578.912735] PM: suspend exit
[16579.210540] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[16579.210543] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[16579.534465] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[16582.715804] wlp1s0: authenticate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6
[16582.720289] wlp1s0: send auth to e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[16582.724681] wlp1s0: authenticated
[16582.731418] wlp1s0: associate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[16582.736159] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[16582.740069] wlp1s0: associated
[16582.748017] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[16596.041151] input: 88:C6:26:69:E2:07 as /devices/virtual/input/input33
[16885.928725] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[16930.036262] perf: interrupt took too long (3128 > 3126), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63750
[20628.935902] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[20639.360723] wlp1s0: authenticate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6
[20639.365279] wlp1s0: send auth to e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[20639.372528] wlp1s0: authenticated
[20639.378401] wlp1s0: associate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[20639.387471] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[20639.399909] wlp1s0: associated
[20639.438688] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[20942.452487] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[21499.713476] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[21502.834242] wlp1s0: authenticate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6
[21502.839464] wlp1s0: send auth to e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[21502.850494] wlp1s0: authenticated
[21502.853944] wlp1s0: associate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[21502.860790] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[21502.875779] wlp1s0: associated
[21508.477496] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[21571.059696] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[21571.072627] wlp1s0: authenticate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6
[21571.077726] wlp1s0: send auth to e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[21571.080704] wlp1s0: authenticated
[21571.083678] wlp1s0: associate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[21571.089123] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[21571.103622] wlp1s0: associated
[21605.753884] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[21605.772075] wlp1s0: authenticate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6
[21605.776257] wlp1s0: send auth to e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[21605.779792] wlp1s0: authenticated
[21605.780639] wlp1s0: associate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[21605.784057] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[21605.787378] wlp1s0: associated
[21611.000174] perf: interrupt took too long (3959 > 3910), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50500
[21906.428930] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[22013.453957] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[22014.843407] wlp1s0: authenticate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6
[22014.848019] wlp1s0: send auth to e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[22014.860754] wlp1s0: authenticated
[22014.865338] wlp1s0: associate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[22014.871531] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[22014.878254] wlp1s0: associated
[22157.410676] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[22158.821671] wlp1s0: authenticate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6
[22158.826649] wlp1s0: send auth to e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[22158.835156] wlp1s0: authenticated
[22158.846385] wlp1s0: associate with e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (try 1/3)
[22158.853009] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from e8:ad:a6:4b:d7:a6 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[22158.858668] wlp1s0: associated
[22461.074514] IPv6: ipv6_create_tempaddr: retry temporary address regeneration
[22536.382236] kauditd_printk_skb: 52 callbacks suppressed
[22536.382238] audit: type=1400 audit(1555737920.125:63): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/sbin/dhclient" pid=29776 comm="dhclient" capability=16  capname="sys_module"
[23667.804427] ACPI Error: Thread 4232142336 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 2357362688 (20181213/exmutex-382)
[23667.804443] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q66]
[23667.804446] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q66]
[23667.804449] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_AML_NOT_OWNER (20181213/psparse-531)
[24143.582771] mce: CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[24143.582772] mce: CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[24143.582773] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[24143.582774] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[24143.582776] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[24143.582777] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[24143.585801] mce: CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[24143.585802] mce: CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[24143.585803] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[24143.585803] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[24143.585804] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[24143.585805] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[24521.183340] perf: interrupt took too long (5165 > 4948), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 38500
[50837.541854] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50837.541917] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50837.565708] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50837.565744] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50843.541784] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50843.541821] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50843.565534] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50843.565556] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50844.088045] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[50844.088047] Timeout waiting for hardware access (CSR_GP_CNTRL 0xffffffff)
[50844.088085] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 538 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2030 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1ee/0x220 [iwlwifi]
[50844.088086] Modules linked in: cmac nls_utf8 isofs ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter ccm snd_hda_codec_hdmi rfcomm 8021q garp mrp bnep stp llc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec kvm_intel snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul joydev crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event i915 arc4 ghash_clmulni_intel snd_rawmidi kvmgt vfio_mdev mdev dell_laptop ledtrig_audio vfio_iommu_type1 uvcvideo dell_smm_hwmon videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops aesni_intel iwlmvm vfio mac80211 videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq btusb kvm aes_x86_64 videobuf2_common btrtl crypto_simd irqbypass iwlwifi cryptd btbcm glue_helper dell_wmi intel_cstate btintel dell_smbios intel_rapl_perf dcdbas videodev
[50844.088102]  input_leds drm_kms_helper cfg80211 serio_raw dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof hid_multitouch media drm bluetooth snd_seq_device hid_sensor_magn_3d hid_sensor_incl_3d snd_timer hid_sensor_accel_3d hid_sensor_rotation i2c_algo_bit hid_sensor_gyro_3d hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf snd hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio intel_pch_thermal mei_me fb_sys_fops syscopyarea ecdh_generic sysfillrect intel_xhci_usb_role_switch idma64 processor_thermal_device roles virt_dma soundcore sysimgblt mei intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal soc_button_array intel_vbtn intel_hid sparse_keymap mac_hid int3400_thermal int3402_thermal acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub hid_generic intel_ishtp_hid ahci psmouse i2c_i801 libahci intel_lpss_pci intel_ish_ipc intel_lpss i2c_hid intel_ishtp hid wmi pinctrl_sunrisepoint video pinctrl_intel
[50844.088122] CPU: 2 PID: 538 Comm: CompositorTileW Not tainted 5.0.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu
[50844.088122] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 15-5578/0H20TW, BIOS 1.26.0 07/17/2018
[50844.088127] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1ee/0x220 [iwlwifi]
[50844.088128] Code: cb f9 49 8d 57 08 bf 00 20 00 00 e8 ec e7 52 f8 e9 36 ff ff ff 89 c6 48 c7 c7 a8 a2 9a c0 c6 05 73 a9 02 00 01 e8 44 03 51 f8 <0f> 0b e9 f1 fe ff ff 48 8b 7b 30 48 c7 c1 10 a3 9a c0 31 d2 31 f6
[50844.088129] RSP: 0000:ffff92efff303dc0 EFLAGS: 00010082
[50844.088129] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff92eff4f40018 RCX: 0000000000000006
[50844.088130] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: ffff92efff316440
[50844.088130] RBP: ffff92efff303de8 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000476
[50844.088131] R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
[50844.088131] R13: ffff92eff4f4a434 R14: ffff92efff303df8 R15: 00000000ffffffff
[50844.088132] FS:  00007f186e32e700(0000) GS:ffff92efff300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[50844.088133] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[50844.088133] CR2: 00007f2fc942c000 CR3: 000000024d546003 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[50844.088134] Call Trace:
[50844.088135]  <IRQ>
[50844.088139]  iwl_read_prph+0x38/0x90 [iwlwifi]
[50844.088144]  iwl_trans_pcie_log_scd_error+0x13b/0x210 [iwlwifi]
[50844.088148]  iwl_pcie_txq_stuck_timer+0x4b/0x70 [iwlwifi]
[50844.088151]  ? iwl_pcie_tfd_unmap.isra.35+0x1e0/0x1e0 [iwlwifi]
[50844.088153]  call_timer_fn+0x30/0x130
[50844.088154]  run_timer_softirq+0x3ea/0x420
[50844.088155]  ? ktime_get+0x3c/0xa0
[50844.088157]  ? lapic_next_deadline+0x26/0x30
[50844.088159]  ? clockevents_program_event+0x93/0xf0
[50844.088161]  __do_softirq+0xdc/0x2f3
[50844.088162]  irq_exit+0xc0/0xd0
[50844.088163]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x79/0x140
[50844.088164]  apic_timer_interrupt+0xf/0x20
[50844.088165]  </IRQ>
[50844.088166] RIP: 0033:0x7f187cdde2b1
[50844.088167] Code: f8 03 0f 84 81 01 00 00 4c 89 ef e8 b9 e6 ff ff 41 89 c0 85 c0 45 0f 44 c7 48 8b 8c 24 88 00 00 00 64 48 33 0c 25 28 00 00 00 <44> 89 c0 0f 85 58 03 00 00 48 81 c4 98 00 00 00 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d
[50844.088167] RSP: 002b:00007f186e32d760 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
[50844.088168] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 000006c7ea66c800 RCX: 0000000000000000
[50844.088168] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000002
[50844.088169] RBP: 000006c7ea66c824 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[50844.088169] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 000006c7ea66c82c
[50844.088170] R13: 000006c7ea66c730 R14: 0000000000000b19 R15: 0000000000000000
[50844.088171] ---[ end trace 8ccf11f382fd93bf ]---
[50844.088174] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[50844.088176] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[50844.088195] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[50844.088196] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[50844.088197] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[50844.088211] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[50844.088212] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[50844.088477] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.0) config registers:
[50844.088490] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.0: 00000000: 9d148086 00100007 060400f1 00810000 00000000 00000000 00010100 200000f0
[50844.088491] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.0: 00000020: d100d100 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 0010010b
[50844.088492] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi root port (0000:00:1c.0) AER cap structure:
[50844.088501] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.0: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 000010c1 00002000 00000000 00000000
[50844.088502] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[50844.155432] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Queue 10 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [68, 84] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
[50849.540124] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50849.540143] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50849.562552] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50849.562566] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50855.541242] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50855.541298] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50855.564998] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50855.565020] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50861.541328] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50861.541368] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50861.565125] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50861.565151] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50867.541072] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50867.541119] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50867.566097] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50867.566156] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50873.536149] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50873.536191] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50873.558443] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50873.558571] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50879.541677] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50879.541836] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50879.565625] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50879.565648] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50885.539137] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50885.539185] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50885.562755] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50885.562778] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50891.535528] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50891.535606] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50891.557900] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50891.557921] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50897.538773] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50897.538956] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50897.562503] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50897.562519] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50903.537383] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50903.537620] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50903.561514] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50903.561829] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50909.540562] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50909.540588] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50909.564060] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50909.564081] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50915.535969] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50915.536023] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50915.558415] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50915.558440] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50921.535459] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50921.535522] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50921.557537] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50921.557559] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50927.535902] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50927.535950] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50927.557918] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50927.557943] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50933.537449] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50933.537679] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50933.561451] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50933.561718] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50939.537463] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50939.537508] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50939.560766] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50939.560791] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50945.541432] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50945.541465] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[50945.565291] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[50945.565336] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
```

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too on Ubuntu 19.04. Set my IPv6 to a manual configured fixed IP and it works OK.  I think the authority time for the temporary connection is set too low somewhere, so it keep re-connecting.

Comment: IPv6 has historically been a pain for me. Lots of times I just shut it off and simply use IPv4. Have your first +1 for your answer though.